# how to bring smooth swipe experience for react native flat list

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-native-scrollview, react-native-swiper

I have implemented a FlatList in my React Native app to render elements vertically. Each element takes up the height of the screen, and the user can see one element at a time. Upon scrolling, the user can view the next elements in the list. To improve the swipe experience, I have implemented pagination to load more elements as the user swipes.

Currently, I have referred to the following repository for implementing this feature: [repo](https://github.com/sonalmaniya/insta-reels)

While the swipe functionality is working, I would like to make the swipe experience even smoother and more user-friendly. Can you suggest any ways to achieve this? Are there any specific techniques, libraries, or best practices that I should consider to enhance the swipe experience in my FlatList with pagination?

Any suggestions, code snippets, or examples would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!